# React Native stylesheet merge: Spread types may only be created from object types

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to merge an existing style with my extra styling in React Native's regular `StyleSheet.create` method:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    blurView:{
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
        borderRadius: 24
    },

});
```

However I'm getting the following error on line `...StyleSheet.absoluteFill`:

`Spread types may only be created from object types.`

What am I doing wrong? I know I can pass an array into `style` prop, but I'm just curious why this isn't working.

Comment: This seems like a typing issue - I'm not sure what type you're seeing for `StyleSheet.absoluteFill` and I'm not super familiar with typescript but perhaps you can find a way to explicitly tell typescript that `StyleSheet.absoluteFill` is an object, something like `...(StyleSheet.absoluteFill as object),` perhaps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Changing `StyleSheet.absoluteFill` to `StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject` fixed the issue. Apparently spread operator doesn't play well with registered styles.